# Clicking to create multiple icons on map using OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to build python-based (flask) application where multiple icons can be
placed on an openstreetmap by clicking on the various spots where I want an icon. I am trying to
achieve that using OpenLayers 4. Here is what I have tried:

```js
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
   image: new ol.style.Icon({
      size: [21, 25],
      offset: [0, 0],
    //  src: 'C:\flask_apps\click_coord\images\mark.png'
      src:'{{url_for('static', filename='mark.png')}}'
   })
});

var map = new ol.Map({

   layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
   target: 'map',
   view: new ol.View({
     center: [0, 0],
     zoom: 2
   })
 });

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();

var source_name = 'iconSource';
vectorSource.set('name',source_name);

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: vectorSource,
   style: iconStyle
});


var layer_name = 'iconLayer';

vectorLayer.set('name',layer_name); 

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);


map.on('click', function(evt) {
   var position = evt.coordinate;

   var mlayers = map.getLayers();
   var length = mlayers.getLength(), l;

   for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      l = mlayers.item(i);


     if(layer_name ===l.get('name')) {


       var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
         geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([position], 'EPSG:4326',     
         'EPSG:3857'))

       });

       iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

       this.vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(iconFeature);
       this.vectorLayer.clear();
       //   this.vectorLayer.redraw();
       //   this.vectorLayer.changed();
       //   this.vectorLayer.refresh({force:true});

     }  
   }

 });
```

I have checked using view page source that the framework is resolving the path to the icon image
properly. I had previously hard-coded the location of the icon image. Irrespective of what I try, nothing
happens when I click the map. I have tried refreshing the map (I may not be doing this properly), that
doesn't seem to work either.

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

I am using OpenLayers 4.2.0

Comment: Your code doesn't have any click event registered which add some marker or feature. Have you checked or tried `map.on('click', )`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Actually you don't need to transform your point geometry from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857, since the map is already in EPSG:3857. As [stated in the openlayers doc](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html), the default projection of the map is always EPSG:3857.

So change your code as:

```
   var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
      geometry: new ol.geom.Point(position)
   });
```

I also remove the `this` before the        `vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(iconFeature);` because it refers to the `evt`.

```
vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(iconFeature);
```

I got also an error with vectorLayer.clear() which was not recognized, so I remove this line.

I tried this on Google Chrome 59.0.3071.11 with openlayers 3.8.2.

Comment: Thanks juminet...I had tried that previously before posting my question and tried it again after your suggestion and both times, the map wouldn't load. I would get a blank page. With the clear() function, reading the apidocs for different versions got me somewhat confused as to whether it was a vector layer method or a vector source method. From the apidocs for 4.2.0, it seems to be a vector source method and I have also tested the program as such and I am still having the same issue. Appreciate the effort.

Comment: Strange that it doesn't work. I tried with the same code as yours, except the ol.style.Icon src. Don't you have any messages in the web console?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Comment: So is it OK now?

Comment: Hello juminet. I get the following error when I check the console: SyntaxError: missing : after property id. When I checked the apidoc for 4.2.0, the ol.geom.Point constructor takes a ol.geom.GeometryLayout parameter in addition to coordinates. So my constructor looks like this: new ol.geom.Point(evt.coordinate,ol.geom.GeometryLayout.XY). However I still get the same error. When I use geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([position], 'EPSG:4326',   'EPSG:3857')), there are no errors in the console, but when I click the map, nothing happens. What broswer/version are you using?

Comment: Hello juminet, could you please state which browser and browser version you were using? Could you state the openlayers version you were using and the link to that particular versions library as would be placed in script tags? (I don't want to work with the downloaded library). Thank you

Comment: Hi sorry I did also remove the "this.". Please try the code now, I've updated my answer.

Comment: `ol.proj.transform([position], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')` is weird! Instead use `ol.proj.fromLonLat([position.lon, position.lat])`